# Maven dependencies for hadoop and yarn

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Why do certain maven dependencies give me jdk.tools.1.8.jar errors and others don't?

For example, the below dependancy does not cause any problems

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But then the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

causes

```
Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8
```

I'm using java 1.7 which is jdk1.7.0_71 and not a JRE.
My execution environment is set to this 
I know there are other similar threads but I can't get this working.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get rid of the issue by including the following dependency but it still doesn't make sense that this should depend on jdk1.8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```